# Filter Realm results by child list

Tags: javascript, realm

In my realm DB (javascript) I have a schema that looks like this:

```
const ItemSchema = {
  name: 'Item',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    title: {type: 'string'},
    tags: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Tag'}
    ...
```

Now, how can I filter items with a certain Tag? (i.e. tags with `title` matching a given string) ? I know with a single `tag` child item I would just do a filter on `tag.title`, but how is this done with a list?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported yet so at the moment, you would have to do it in memory with a regular `.filter()` call or a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It might help

```
real.objects(ItemSchema.name).filtered("tags.title = $0", title)
```